# How do I check for a true boolean value and then set all other values to false in my MVC Web Application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a car rental application, I list all the current hires that are taking place at the moment.  One car can have many rentals but can only have one rental active at any one time.  To achieve this we have a column called active that accepts a boolean value of true or false, this is done via a checkbox in my form.

```
@Html.CheckboxFor(m => m.Active)
```

What I would like to do is introduce a check whenever a new rental is added or an existing rental is updated.  If the Active flag is set to true on that particular update or addition, then set all the other rentals for that particular car to false.

I'm not sure how to achieve this, I know that it would take place in the controller, something like:

```
public ActionResult AddRental(ProjectRental rental)
{
    try {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                if (rental.Active == true) {
                    //do something here to set the flags.
                    //var rentalActiveCheck = uow.RentalRepository.Get().Any(x => x.Active == payload.Active && x.CarID == payload.CarId);
                }
                uow.RentalRepository.Insert(rental);
                uow.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (DataException dex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dex);
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Unable to save changes. Try again.");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

A similar method would be used for the update I'm guessing.  So, to summarise, whenever a hire period for a particular car is added or an existing one updated that has the active flag set to "true" set the other records to false.  This is to make sure there is only ever one active hire for a car at a particular time.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. After you have the list of active rentals, you can update the field in one step:

```
var rentalActiveList = uow.RentalRepository.Get().Any(x => x.Active == payload.Active && x.CarID == payload.CarId);
rentalActiveList.ForEach(r => r.Active = false);
...
uow.Save();
```

On an update, you will need to exclude the current rental from the list by adding something like `&& x.RentalID != rental.RentalID`